# Server error 500 when trying to upload file on laravel application hosted on digital ocean

Tags: php, linux, laravel, laravel-5, digital-ocean

I am facing an issue when I try to upload this excel file that gets processed and stored in the database. On my localhost this is working so I can upload the file and using laravel-excel, it is being saved in the database.

However, on the same laravel app hosted on digital ocean, I am always getting 500 Internal server errors when I try to submit the file, Can somebody help?

[image]

http {

```
##
# Basic Settings
##

sendfile on;
tcp_nopush on;
tcp_nodelay on;
keepalive_timeout 65;
types_hash_max_size 2048;
# server_tokens off;

# server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
# server_name_in_redirect off;

include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type application/octet-stream;

##
# SSL Settings
##

ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

##
# Logging Settings
##

access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

##
# Gzip Settings
##

gzip on;

# gzip_vary on;
# gzip_proxied any;
# gzip_comp_level 6;
# gzip_buffers 16 8k;
# gzip_http_version 1.1;
# gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

##
# Virtual Host Configs
##

include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
```

Comment: `500` is a very generic server error, you will need to check your server logs.

Comment: do you mean in this file sudo cat /var/log/nginx/error.log because even there I cant find the recent logs for that

Comment: did you check your "upload_max_size" and "post_max_size" configurations ? how to change = https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/change-the-maximum-upload-file-size

Comment: still now working ,I am trying to upload a file that is 112KB and max size is 2MB

Comment: nginx has a generic server log `/var/log/nginx/error.log` but there should also be a site specific error log defined in your nginx config file.

Comment: I have added the nginx settings

Comment: Can you show us the controller when the file is being uploaded?